# Some weird results in fetch request - Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have the following predicate, but I'm getting some really weird results after fetch request.

Predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parkingEndTime > %f",floor(timestamp)];
```

Example:

- timestamp = 1 391 689 631
- Results:    1 391 689 612
- 1 391 689 625

Here's full code:

```
+ (NSArray *)getParkedCars {
    AppDelegate *myAppDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *ctx = [myAppDelegate getThreadSafeManagedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Car"];

    NSTimeInterval timestamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSLog(@"Parking End Time: %f",floor(timestamp));
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parkingEndTime > %f",floor(timestamp)];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *result = [ctx executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Fetched request: %@",[result firstObject]);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Try using `%lf` in the predicate

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by converting it to an NSNumber before comparing:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parkingEndTime > %@",@(floor(timestamp))];
```